# How to fetch tweets from a specific twitter user using python

Tags: python, twitter, python-requests

I just started looking at the twitter API and found there isn't a resource for how to do what I want to do. I just want a python script which looks at a specific user and fetches the link for every one of their tweets, I found a lot of guides for how to search queries but none for how to just watch a specific user. I think python requests can be used for this but I have never used it before, its just referenced in a lot of guides.

Comment: Even with a developer account, you are limited to the most recent ~3,200 tweets of an account using the user-timeline endpoint. Even so, its not clear from the question what you mean by "all the links": do you mean literal urls or do you mean tweet objects? The Twitter API docs are here: developer.twitter.com/en/docs/api-reference-index Note that you don't need to use requests or similar unless you are intent on writing your own python api interface; Just use tweepy or twython or similar existing library.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can only get tweets from the past 7 days unless you go through some extra steps like creating a developer account. Did you create one of these already?

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/explore-a-users-tweets

I would just go ahead and create one and see if REST API requests allows you to get full history of tweets.

If you are new to programming you could try a python module that has some stuff already built in like tweepy.

https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/getting_started.html#hello-tweepy

Comment: Yes I already made an account for access to the api